# Inno Setup Always on Top

Tags: inno-setup

We usually run our installers via LANDesk. recently we had a request to always have the windows on top. The command line we run is /SP- /SILENT /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES /NORESTART /LOG="C:\LOGS\logfile.LOG" /NOCANCEL for an automated install. I've searched everywhere and for the life of me can't find a way to complete this. Has anyone ever completed an install with the dialogs always displaying on top?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like:

```
[Code]
const
  HWND_TOPMOST = -1;
  SWP_NOSIZE = 1;
  SWP_NOMOVE = 2;
  SWP_SHOWWINDOW = $40;

function SetWindowPos(hWnd: HWND; hWndInsertAfter: HWND; X: Integer; Y: Integer;
  cx: Integer; cy: Integer; uFlags: UINT): BOOL;
  external 'SetWindowPos@user32.dll stdcall'; 

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  SetWindowPos(WizardForm.Handle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE or 
    SWP_NOMOVE or SWP_SHOWWINDOW); 
end;
```

Comment: I'm afraid this has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: That makes the Wizard Window always on top. Maybe I just didn't get the problem...

Comment: THANK YOU so much, this worked perfectly for me. I googled and found your answer so I don't know where it is not in relation with the one of OP, but it saved me from an ordeal. +40 if I could.